# AM Forms not Submitting

Tags: templating, plugin-amforms

I have a form created with [AM forms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms) that on submission does nothing. It doesn't go to the redirect url and nothing is saved to the database. Not sure what I am missing.

Here is my simplified code:

```html
{% set form = craft.amForms.getForm('clubMembershipApplication') %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 bv-form">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}

  {# This should always be here! #}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="amForms/submissions/saveSubmission">

  {# Insert your forms handle. #}
  <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="{{ form.handle }}">

  {# Optional: Redirect URL. Will redirect to current page by default. #}
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="membership/thankyou">

  various fields here

  <div class="submit-btn-container col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="solo-btn btn">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are submissions enabled on the form in the control panel?

Comment: Also, have you tried `{{ dump(form) }}` to see what it contains or `{{ form | length }}` to see if anything is being set?

Comment: Actually `form` is being set properly if you are seeing the form in the first place. Otherwise Craft might give you an error because it wouldn't be able to access `handle` if `{{ form.handle }}` if it were `null`.

Comment: @cavellblood save submissions is enabled. And {{ form | length }} outputs a number